# Excel Loop which adds time

Tags: excel, vba, loops

is there a more efficient way to loop this i need to do this from 7 am -9 pm. in excel i fill in the rows and the formula then writes in the cell the time (7 am to 2 Pm)

```
For a = 5 To 22
  If Sheet3.Range("a" & a).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone And Sheet3.Range("b" & a & ":e" & a).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 Then
    Sheet1.Range("C" & a).Cells = "7 a"
    Sheet1.Range("D" & a).Cells = "9 a"
  End If
Next a

For a = 5 To 22
  If Sheet3.Range("a" & a).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone And Sheet3.Range("b" & a & ":f" & a).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 Then
    Sheet1.Range("C" & a).Cells = "7 a"
    Sheet1.Range("D" & a).Cells = "9:30 a"
  End If
Next a
```

Comment: Please show us an example of the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, looping over a range of cells can be slow.

When referencing some properties, including `.Interior`, to test for or set to the *same* value, you can reference a range of >=1 cells in one go.
(Note: if not all values are the same, the reference will return `NULL`)

So, your `Sub` can be optimised as:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set rng = sh.Range("A5:A22")

    If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone And sh.Range("B5:F22").Interior.ColorIndex = 46 Then
        sh.Range("C5:C22") = "7 a"
        sh.Range("D5:D22") = "9:30 a"
    ElseIf rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone And sh.Range("B5:E22").Interior.ColorIndex = 46 Then
        sh.Range("C5:C22") = "7 a"
        sh.Range("D5:D22") = "9 a"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make sure that the code below actually works, but it should. Basically what I did is I minimized the number of times you are checking the `Range` conditions. By minimizing the calling to the `range` properties I thereby minimize the number of calls to Excel, which speeds up the process. I also used `boolean` variables to make it so VBA doesn't have to reference the objects too often.

```
Sub ColorTimes()

    Dim b9Union As Boolean, b930Union As Boolean, b7Union As Boolean, bContinue As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rColorNone As Range, rColors49BF As Range, rColors49BE As Range
    Dim rLoop As Range, r7A As Range, r9A As Range, r930A As Range
    Dim wks3 As Worksheet

    'Initialize variables
    Set wks3 = Sheet3
    With wks3
        Set rColorNone = .Range("A5:A22")
        Set rColors49BE = .Range("B5:E22")
        Set rColors49BF = .Range("B5:F22")
    End With
    i = -1: bUnion = False

    'Loop through range in column A.
    For Each rLoop In rColorNone
        i = i + 1
        'Check column A first, VBA automatically checks
        'all values in AND statements, so you need to split them up.
        If rLoop.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then
            bContinue = True
            'Check first conditions, if true then don't bother checking the next conditions.
            If rColors49BF.Resize(1).Offset(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 Then
                Time7A9A r7A, r9A, wks3, b7Union, b930Union, i + 5
                b7Union = True: b930Union = True
                bContinue = False
            End If
            If bContinue Then
                If rColors49BE.Resize(1).Offset(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 Then
                    Time7A9A r7A, r9A, wks3, b7Union, b9Union, i + 5
                    b7Union = True: b9Union = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rLoop

    If Not r7A Is Nothing Then r7A = "7 a"
    If Not r9A Is Nothing Then r9A = "9 a"
    If Not r930A Is Nothing Then r930A = "9:30 a"

End Sub
Private Sub Time7A9A(ByRef r7A As Range, ByRef r9A As Range, ByRef wks As Worksheet _
        , ByVal b7Union As Boolean, b9Union As Boolean, ByVal iRow As Integer)

    If b7Union Then
        Set r7A = Union(r7A, wks.Cells(iRow, 3))
    Else
        Set r7A = wks.Cells(iRow, 3)
    End If

    If b9Union Then
        Set r9A = Union(r9A, wks.Cells(iRow, 4))
    Else
        Set r9A = wks.Cells(iRow, 4)
    End If

End Sub
```